# Прототипирование сайта

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Какие есть актуальные методы для прототипирования сайта? Сейчас Photoshop уже не используют? Вместо него какие то другие программы? Или все же использование фотошопа еще актуально?

Comment: Их очень много. Куча программ и онлайн сервисов, используйте для начала Гугл

Comment: Да, фотошоп все еще актуален :)

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать Moqups, лучше всего используйте уже готовый шаблон окна браузера.

Comment: Morya Yaroslav - А фотошоп - плохой уже?

Comment: У нас в компании не используют, а вообще не знаю.
Просто Moqups уже заточен под создание прототипов,  не только под Web, но iOS, свои шаблоны можно подгружать ещё.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?